# ListView not displaying until I swipe the screen

Tags: c#, android, xaml, listview, maui

I trying to implement  [StateContainer by Patrick McCurley](https://github.com/xDelivered-Patrick/Xamarin.Forms.Essentials) in my .NET MAUI application.
It works correctly when the ListView displayed for the first time.
But ListView is not displaying when state changes again until I swipe the screen.

When I add any view element (label, button, etc.) to the view that contains the ListView, it does not show up. But ListView displayed correctly when I move StateContainer to Grid with any other view elements. ListView does not display correctly if the Grid contains no other elements than the StateContainer.

I can't figure out what's the problem here. Grid with other view elements is not a solution for me, because my page should not contain any other elements whan the StateContainer.

Here is an example that reproduces the problem:

P.S. I'm sorry for a lot of code :) I don't know where the problem could be.

States.cs

```
public enum States
{
    Loading, 
    Success
}
```

StateCondition.cs

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class StateCondition : View
{
    public object State { get; set; }
    public View Content { get; set; }
}
```

StateContainer.cs

```
[ContentProperty("Conditions")]
public class StateContainer : ContentView
{
    public List<StateCondition> Conditions { get; set; } = new();

    public static readonly BindableProperty StateProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(State), typeof(object), typeof(StateContainer), null, BindingMode.Default, null, StateChanged);

    private static void StateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var parent = bindable as StateContainer;
        if (parent != null)
            parent.ChooseStateProperty(newValue);
    }

    public object State
    {
        get { return GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ChooseStateProperty(object newValue)
    {
        if (Conditions == null && Conditions?.Count == 0) return;

        var stateCondition = Conditions
            .FirstOrDefault(condition =>
                condition.State != null &&
                condition.State.ToString().Equals(newValue.ToString()));

        if (stateCondition == null) return;

        Content = stateCondition.Content;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage ...>

    <state:StateContainer State="{Binding State}">

        <state:StateCondition State="Loading">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" />
                <Label Text="Updating data..." />
            </StackLayout>
        </state:StateCondition>

        <state:StateCondition State="Success">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding . }" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </state:StateCondition>

    </state:StateContainer>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private States _state;
    private int[] _someData;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;

        SomeData = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        State = States.Success;

        // it can be executed from outside the page
        _ = Task.Run(ExecuteSomeWorkAsync);
    }

    public States State
    {
        get => _state;
        private set
        {
            if (_state != value)
            {
                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public int[] SomeData
    {
        get => _someData;
        private set
        {
            if (_someData != value)
            {
                _someData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task ExecuteSomeWorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        State = States.Loading;

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        // generate new data for displaying
        Random rnd = new();
        var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(n => rnd.Next(0, 5)).ToArray();

        SomeData = data;
        State = States.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: More code is usually better than less as long as it belongs to the problem domain. Have you checked the issues on the MAUI GitHub repo? Maybe there's a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: *"But ListView is not displaying when state changes again until I swipe the screen."* Yep. There are many cases where ListView and CollectionView fail to update dynamically after a change. Even forcing a layout doesn't fix it. I don't know if this specific case is listed as an issue, but I assume that once the underlying problem is fixed, all similar issues will be solved too. If you take the time to make a public github repo, and post it as an issue at the above link, that might be helpful to the devs. Also should help raise the priority of the underlying problem.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks! I created [issue request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10453).

Comment: @ewerspej, thanks. I found my problem in [this closed issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6377) at the 3rd point, but it does not contain solution for this issue.

Comment: *"ListView does not display correctly"*. Please say **exactly** what displays incorrectly. And what lines of code that corresponds to. Because Maui is cross-platform, it does not work well to manipulate lists of views that are not on the display, such as `List<StateCondition> Conditions;` Instead, read about MVVM. Manipulate **viewmodel data**, that has NO UI elements in it. Instead of `Content = stateCondition.Content`, you will change a property of viewmodel, which will result in a different UI being built. Its a different way of thinking.

Comment: ... Actually there may be a way to do what you are trying to do. Add to question the code that **sets** one of the `stateCondition.Content`s. It will need to be done differently.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I have left in this example a minimum of code that reproduces the problem. My main project is using MVVM. View model contains a State property. The StateContainer is bound to this property in the view model. When the view model changes the State property, the UI changes too. It looks good, but not works :)

Comment: I meant that it doesn't show up at all until I swipe the screen.

Comment: Content = stateCondition.Content; executed when the binded StateProperty is changed in the StateContainer. The binding source is a State property in the MainPage. This property changes by the ExecuteSomeWorkAsync method. During debugging, it was seen that the Content property is changing correctly, but the ListView was not displayed until I swipe the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `Content = stateCondition.Content;` won't update display correctly.

As an alternative solution, define `public class StateContainer : StackLayout`, and use `IsVisible="True"/"False"` on each child, to control what is shown. All the stateConditions continue to be children of stateContainer, but make only one visible at a time.